# Visual Studio Online TFS Build Task - File not being copied

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, continuous-integration

I am trying to **copy a DLL file from a specified location to a drop folder** which is used for release automation.

I have VS Online using TFS.

I have a simple build task configured below whereby the source file CRMPackage.dll to be copied is under the Debug folder:

[image]

When I run the build task I get a successful outcome but the DLL file is not showing up under the Drop folder

```
2018-01-25T02:33:08.7648437Z found 1 files
2018-01-25T02:33:08.7653520Z Copying d:\a\1\s\CodeBase\XXXXXXX.CRM\XXXXX.DeploymentPackage\CRMPackage\CRMPackage\bin\Debug\CRMPackage.dll to $\XXXX Dynamics CRM\CodeBase\XXXXX.CRM\Drop\CRMPackage.dll
2018-01-25T02:33:08.7772515Z ##[section]Finishing: Copy Files to: Drop
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Yes, sorry just got back form my long weekend ! Thanks for your response Cece, I tried what you did and used $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) but I am unsure how to specify this variable. In the end I changed the Target directory to d:\a\1\s\CodeBase\****.CRM\Drop and it worked !

Comment: Variable $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) is predefined. It's the local path on the agent where any artifacts are copied to before being pushed to their destination. For example: c:\agent\_work\1\a. Check this link for more information.

Comment: Yes, I have accepted it thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not specify a server path in `Target Folder`. If it works, it means your source will be changed.

You need to type a folder path (eg, d:\a\1\s) or UNC path (require private build agent). In most cases you specify this folder using a variable (eg, $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)), as your hosted agent may not be able to access all location in the hosted build agent machine.

In order to see the copied files on host, you can add a task `Publish Build Artifacts` after `Copy files` task. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

In this way, you can see the copied files in the Artifacts[image]:

Answer (score 0):

For the build task I changed the Target folder to:

d:\a\1\s\CodeBase******.CRM\Drop

[image]

and I managed to get it to work. 
Now I can see the file CRMPackage.dll in my Drop folder when I browse my artefacts.

[image]

However, I am unsure of how to use the $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) variable. Where to I set this?